# Objective-C : Synchronized blocks and GCD

Tags: objective-c, opengl, grand-central-dispatch, synchronized

I have an OpenGL app that needs to perform some computations in the background before displaying data.

Sequentially, what I'm doing is :

1. `prepareData` (calls background thread)
2. `_doLongComputation` (in background thread, calls `_transferToGPU`)
3. `_transferToGPU` (main thread)

Since I'm using `synchronized` blocks on the same object `glData`, critical sections shouldn't be accessed by more than one thread at the same time, but unfortunately this isn't the case, and I can't figure out why.

Any ideas?

*The important parts of the code are below :*

```
@property (atomic, retain) NSData *glData;

...snip snip...

- (void) _doLongComputation {
  @synchronized (glData) {
    // Create a buffer (long operation, done in C++)
    unsigned long size;
    unsigned char* buffer = createBuffer(&size);

    // Create NSData to hold it safely
    self.glData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:size freeWhenDone:YES];
  }

  // Don't wand to deal with locking the OpenGL context,
  // so we do all the OpenGL-related stuff in the main queue
  dispatch_async (dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self _transferToGPU];
  });
}

- (void) _transferToGPU {
  @synchronized (glData) {
    ...snip snip...

    // Transfer buffer to GPU
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                 glData.length,
                 glData.bytes,
                 GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // We're done, so set the buffer to nil
    self.glData = nil;
  }
}

- (void) prepareData {
  [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(_doLongComputation)];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should synchronize on self instead.

Synchronizing on a variable conceptually creates an implicit mutex using the address pointed to by that variable. If the variable points to a different object, it will be a different mutex, even if it's still the same variable in your code. This means that setting glData in your `@synchronized(glData)` blocks defeats the purpose of your synchronization attempt.

Comment: Aw, damn, I was sure it was pretty obvious! Of course the worst happens and my object gets deallocated so the mutex is useless. Thanks for catching that ;)